# Maven aggregate pom skip released modules

Tags: maven, aggregate, release, snapshot, multi-module

This is probably supported, so I apologize if the answer is trivial, but I can't find an answer.

I have a multimodule (aggregate) pom containing a number of modules with interdependencies. Let's say something like:

- infrastructure
- framework
- business-module1
- business-module2

At a certain moment, infrastructure is stable, so I can release it. The version is updated to 1.0 and all dependencies to it are updated to that version as well.

When doing a local install, the module is still build. I know want to avoid building the 1.0 version locally, since it is released and costs build time. The question could be rephrased to, never build a released module.

I have quite a lot of modules in a multimodule setup, and only want to build snapshots. I know that I can skip modules using command line options, but don't want to repeat all these modules. Besides, from the version declarations, it should be clear to maven which modules to build.